# MAXDOP is set to 0, however, all transactions run in serial

Tags: sql, sql-server, parallel-processing

The server setting for `MAXDOP` is set to 0 and the threshold is default of 5.

All transactions run against the server **run in serial** and not against multiple cores/cpus (Virtual Machine and it has 8 CPUs).

Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64.

There is also a "default" and an "internal" workload group on the machine but both resource governors are not enabled and even disabled, they have `MAXDOP` setting of 0.

I've confirmed that SQL Server has the CPU affinity across all cores/cpus.

I'm kind of lost as to why this server refuses to run transactions in parallel as opposed to all the other machines at this location. I came in noticing that many of the servers here had long `CXPACKET` wait times and many processes were causing wasted CPU overhead. Then the DBA said after reading my evaluation *There is nothing wrong with `MAXDOP` 0 and threshold of 5 because XXXX server never runs in parallel like you say.*

I believe my evaluation of the site is still correct, but this darn server is debunking my evaluation.

I am open to all suggestions as to why this server is not configured and should run in parallel but it doesn't.

Comment: What's the execution plan look like? Everything doesn't automatically run in parallel, it's just that it CAN, but the query analyzer is what determines if the query would have any benefit of running in parallel vs serial. It could easily be the case that your query is not easily run in parallel and thus that's why it isn't

Comment: CXPACKET waits do not mean that CPU time is being wastet. This wit type means that the consumer threads wait for the producers to deliver rows. This wait type does not directly indicate burnt CPU time but time the CPU was doing nothing/something else.

Comment: You say "all transactions". Is this question about one query or about the general workload?

Comment: After reading Darren Kopp and usr's responses I went back to the top queries by CPU and CPU time and ran some others and it looks like I must of grabbed 4 queries prior that just executed in serial despite the low threshold. I just found one that executed in parallel. 

Its very odd as some of the other servers will run a "Select * from mytable" that has 500,000 rows in parallel and this server seems to be less prone to doing that.

Thank you all for help. I have something now to show them that it is running in parallel and that parallelism should be managed at some level.

Comment: I advocate that the question be deleted as the issue is resolved and it will not help future visitors in any way.